# ORDER BY help: How to get Average score PER YEAR?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, average

The following is the question I am trying to answer:
For each year between 2010 and 2013 (including 2010 and 2013), show the average score of movies release in that year. Sort the results by year in descending order. Your output should have two columns: yr, and avg_score.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (yr), (SELECT AVG(score) FROM movie) AS avg_score

FROM movie

WHERE yr BETWEEN 2010 AND 2013

ORDER BY yr DESC;
```

This returns the same average score for all the years as a whole.  I need the average score of each year to show.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and then take the average:

```
SELECT yr, AVG(score) AS avg_score
FROM movie
WHERE yr BETWEEN 2010 AND 2013
GROUP BY yr;
```

When you use an aggregate function such as `AVG` without `GROUP BY`, it will apply to the entire table, hence your current result.